# get second last component of a path from a string with js regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Given string `'/root/hello/hello/world'`

I want to extract the second last component in a path i.e. the 2nd occurrence of hello.

If there's no parent part, I want it to return empty. So string `/world` should return an empty string or null.

How can I extract the last path component using a **regex** or similar?

Language is javascript.

Comment: I didn't understand, what's your rule? Second to last or 2nd occurrence? Or does it have to respect both rules?

Comment: second to last - so given a file name path, get the parent directory name.

Comment: What about `"/world/"`?

Comment: how about this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126201/javascript-regex-of-the-last-word-in-a-string) It should help.

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? Are the solutions given (with split) enough?

Comment: yes split is fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can firstly [`split` the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split.) on the `/` character to convert it into an array:

```
var split = '/root/hello/hello/world'.split('/')

-> ["", "root", "hello", "hello", "world"]
```

You can then grab the penultimate item:

```
var result = split[split.length - 2]
```

...but you may want to check the length of your array first:

```
var result;
if (split.length >= 2)
  result = split[split.length - 2]
```

Comment: I think this was first but I' can only accept it in 8 minutes

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```js
let str = '/root/hello/hello/world';

let result = str.split('/');
console.log(result[result.length-2]);
```

Comment: The chosen answer is a bit confusing when you have a variable that has the same name as the function being called. "split"

This is more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, as requested, you can do it with

```
([^/\n]*)\/[^/\n]*$
```

That captures the second to last part into capture group 1.

The `([^/\n]*)` part captures (inside parentheses) a stretch of characters that isn't a `/`, nor a new line (`\n`). The `\/` ensures it's followed by a `/` and `[^/\n]*$` checks that the line finally is terminated by another stretch without a `/` (or LF).

```js
var pathArray = [
      '/root/hello/cruel/world',
      '/root/hello/world',
      '/root/world',
      '/world'
    ],
    re = /([^/\n]*)\/[^/\n]*$/;
    
pathArray.forEach(function (path) {
  document.write( '"' + path + '" returns "' + re.exec(path)[1] + '"<br/>' );
});
```

[Try it out and experiment with it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QFGCnJ/1).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, you can just split it.

```
const string = '/root/hello/hello/world';

// Split by the '/' character
const stringSplit = string.split('/');

// Slice the array, taking only the last 2 items.
// Then select the first one in the array
const myVal = stringSplit.slice(-2)[0];

// OR, using length
const myValLen = stringSplit[stringSplit.length - 2];

// OR, in one
const myValShort = string.split('/').slice(-2)[0];
```